# Django Singal Populating one model if another model is populated

Tags: django, django-signals

I have a Django project with two apps.. one is `contact` and annother is `contactus`

my contact model is:
`project/contact/models.py` below:

```
from django.db import models

class ContactList(models.Model):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    email = models.EmailField()
```

and my contactus model is:
`project/contactus/models.py` below:

```
from django.db import models

class ContactUs(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    email = models.EmailField()
    message = models.TextField()
```

I want when `ContactUs` class gets data by user input, in the same time, ContactUs's `phone` and `email` should be populated in `ContactList` class

I created two `signal.py` file in my two apps but tried a lost with some code, i failed.. i think this is the very easiest task for expert.. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to do something when data is saved in `ContactUs` you should use the [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save) signal like this:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=ContactUs)
def add_to_list(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        ContactList.objects.create(phone=instance.phone, email=instance.email
```

This signal will create a `ContactList` object when a `ContactUs` object is created and assigns the `phone` and `email` values of the `ContactUs` instance to the `phone` and `email` fields of the `ContactList` object.

More information about Django signals can be found in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/)